# RSpec custom matchers keep state between specs

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I've come across some counter intuitive behavior in RSpec (2.8.0) custom matchers functionality and I wonder whether it is a bug or feature or me being confused. Let's look at the code:

```rb
# matcher code
RSpec::Matchers.define :exist do
  chain :with_start_time do |time|
    @start_time = time
  end

  chain :with_end_time do |time|
    @end_time = time
  end

  match do |subject|
    result = true
    result &&= subject.start_time == @start_time if @start_time
    result &&= subject.end_time == @end_time if @end_time
    result
  end

  failure_message_for_should do |subject|
    "Failure!\n".tap do |msg|
      if @start_time != subject.start_time
        msg << "Expected start_time to be #@start_time but was #{subject.start_time}\n"
      end
      if @end_time != subject.end_time
        msg << "Expected end_time to be #@end_time but was #{subject.end_time}\n"
      end
    end
  end
end

#spec code
require 'ostruct'

describe 'RSpec custom matcher keeping state between tests' do
  let(:time) { Time.now }

  it 'passes the first spec' do
    o = OpenStruct.new(start_time: time)
    o.should exist.with_start_time(time)
  end

  it 'fails the second because matcher kept @start_time from the first test' do
    o = OpenStruct.new(end_time: time)
    o.should exist.with_end_time(time)
  end
end
```

This fails (demonstrating the issue):

```
avetia01:~/projects/custom_matcher_bug% rspec test_spec.rb             
.F

Failures:

  1) RSpec custom matcher keeping state between tests fails the second because matcher kept @start_time from the first test
     Failure/Error: o.should exist.with_end_time(time)
       Failure!
       Expected start_time to be 2012-02-27 12:20:25 +0000 but was 
     # ./test_spec.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00116 seconds

2 examples, 1 failure
```

So the unexpected bit is that the same matcher instance seems to be used across multiple specs. Which, in this particular case leads, to `@start_time` being initialized with the value from the first spec, causing incorrect failure of the second spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has reported and fixed, but not yet released:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/issues/104